# Nesting hierarchical data into an array - PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, recursion

I have been trying to solve this for while but its been a little difficult. the thing is, am trying nest the data from the table bellow into an array in the order by which they are related.

```
+-----+------+------------+
| uid | name | supermember|
+-----+------+------------+
|   1 | A    |      0     |
|   2 | B    |      1     |
|   3 | C    |      1     |
|   4 | D    |      2     |
|   5 | E    |      3     |
|   7 | G    |      3     |
|   9 | H    |      4     |
|  10 | I    |      4     |
|  11 | J    |      7     |
+-----+------+------------+
```

Here is what i have done:

```php
public function getDataAsBinaryTree($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('uid', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('binary_tbl');
        $result = [];
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $k) {
                $result[$k->name] =  $this->tolevels($k->uid);
            }
         } else {
            $result = NULL;
         }
         return $result;  
    }   



    private function tolevels($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('supermember', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('binary_tbl');
        $output = [];
        $count = $query->num_rows();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($query->result() as $key) {
                $output[$key->name] = (($count > 1) ? $this->tolevel($key->uid) : $this->tolevel($key->uid));
            }
        } 
        return $output;
    }
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```php
array(
        'A' => array(
                'B' => array(
                    'D' => array(
                       'H' => 'H',
                        'I' => 'I'
                       )
                     ),
                 'C' => array(
                     'E' => null,
                      'G' => array(
                         'J' => 'J'
                        )
                   )
                )
            );
```

i want the returned data from these methods to be in key and value pair but it instead returned an array with only keys when i var_dump on the `getDataAsBinaryTree(1)` method. I think the problem is from the recursion but i just don't know how to get around it.

**RESULT**

```php
array (size=1)
  'A' => 
    array (size=2)
      'B' => 
        array (size=1)
          'D' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'C' => 
        array (size=2)
          'E' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'G' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
```

Comment: **Side note:** If this hierarchy can have more than 2 children, don't name the method as `getDataAsBinaryTree`.

Comment: Fetch all data at once and then make the array to reduce round trips to DB call to just 1.

Comment: @vivek_23 would you mind giving me sample?

Comment: how is this question different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61532396/converting-a-related-database-table-object-into-a-nested-array-php)?

Comment: @Vickel now you getting it... am stuck?

Comment: What do you mean by key , value pair ? (You already retrieve data in hierarchical manner) Could you post the sample expected output ?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I don't understand your question completely, you should provide the structure of output code. But as your function `getDataAsBinaryTree` suggests you're trying to make a binary tree, if that's the case then this is the way to go.

```
public function getDataAsBinaryTree($id = false){

    // $this->db->where('uid', $id);
    $query  = $this->db->get('binary_tbl');
    $result = [];

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $k) {
            $result[$k->name] =  $this->tolevels($k->uid);
        }
    } else {
       $result = NULL;
    }
    // return $result;
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);  
}

private function tolevels($id){

    $this->db->where('supermember', $id);

    $query  = $this->db->get('binary_tbl');
    $output = [];
    $count  = $query->num_rows();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $key) {
            // $output[$key->name] = ($count > 0) ? $this->tolevels($key->uid) : $key->uid;
            $output[$key->name] = $key->uid;
            if($count > 0){ $this->tolevels($key->uid); };
        }
    } 
    return $output;
}
```

> **OUTPUT**
>
> ```
> Array
> (
>     [A] => Array
>         (
>             [B] => 2
>             [C] => 3
>         )
>
>     [B] => Array
>         (
>             [D] => 4
>         )
>
>     [C] => Array
>         (
>             [E] => 5
>             [G] => 6
>         )
>
>     [D] => Array
>         (
>             [H] => 7
>             [I] => 8
>         )
>
>     [E] => Array
>         (
>         )
>
>     [G] => Array
>         (
>         )
>
>     [H] => Array
>         (
>             [J] => 9
>         )
>
>     [I] => Array
>         (
>         )
>
>     [J] => Array
>         (
>         )
>
> )
> ```

Hope, this helps you. :)

Comment: if it helps, you should know that i don't understand it either. LOL. i just added what the output should look like. think you take a look

Comment: Hehe, Lol. But you should understand that people wouldn't be able to help you unless you yourself aren't clear what you want. Happy coding. :)

Comment: yea... i think i was coding in the air rather than using my laptop actually